# How to make a rigid bodies with constraints animation from .stl

Tags: bones, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I'm new to Blender. I have a basic grasp of the program from playing for a while and learning from videos. What I want to do is to take two irregular surfaces, let's call them stlA and stlB and do the following:
*Make some rope connections between the surfaces (supposing that objects are positioned in a way the rope doesn't go through them). If Xi is the number i vertice of stlX I select to connect. The connections would be A1-B1, A2-B2, and so on. Won't be more than 10.
*Make a connection between one of the surfaces and a "piston" (linear periodic motion) linking them with a rope. Suppose the point of contact of the rope with stlA is Am and that it meets the starting point of the rope and that the point where the "piston" is located Pm meets the ending point of the rope. So that there is a rigid rope link between the "piston" translation and the point Am of stlA
*Have into account gravity forces of stlA and stlB

My starting point are the .stl files. I have imported them and been able to play with them a litte, making them fall and grabing them but I need guidance on what books should I read and tutorials and videos I should follow as I know Blender is used for a wide range of purposes and I have gotten confused by such a large offer of video-tutorials to select from youtube

Edit: Image added

[image: Describing figure]

Comment: Attempting to explain something as detailed as what you're trying to only complicates things for us when trying to understand your situation, and what we could do to help you. Please edit your post to include screenshots/drafts of what you are trying to accomplish, as having something to look at makes it a lot easier for people to help you, instead of visualizing it themselves. It would probably take the same amount of time and effort to read and fully understand your question as it would take to come up with a correct answer. Pictures say a thousand words, use this to your advantage.

Comment: Picture added...